# Accessing file shares on other Mac on Macs with shared connections

Tags: network, mac-pro, file-sharing

It is probably best to first describe the ridiculous network setup I have:

I have a time capsule connected via Ethernet to my university's network. It is sharing this internet connection with a group of Macs over AirPort. Some of the macs are old Mac Pros and do not have AirPort, so they are attached via Ethernet to some of the Macs that have AirPort. The daisy-chained Macs get internet, but they cannot see other computers with file sharing on the LAN. A diagram:

```
TimeCapsule | )))))) | MacPro | -------> | MacPro
            |  wifi  | on LAN | Ethernet | only internet
```

I have noticed that the Macs directly connected (Wi-Fi and Ethernet) to the time capsule have IP addresses that begin with 10, but the daisy-chained machines have IPs beginning with 192.

How can I get the Daisy-chained machines to appear on the LAN?

Comment: You basically want the Mac that is sharing its connection to do so in 'bridge' mode.  As it is now it is acting as a dhcp server.  Unfortunately I don't believe what you are trying to do is supported, tho there may be a hack. The "right" way to do this IMO would be to get a say, 8 port router and set it up in bridge mode.

Comment: Yeah. I was afraid of that. I suppose that theoretically, I could run ethernet cable from the Time capsule.